# Using session in old Petclinic example

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm experimenting with the old Petclinic example and I noticed that the vets ArrayList in the SimpleJdbcClinic exists for the life of the session. It seems like it should exist only for the request since I don't see any annotations putting it into the session context. Could someone point out what I'm failing to understand?

Here is the vets class:
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Vets {

```
   private List<Vet> vets;

   @XmlElement
   public List<Vet> getVetList() {
      if (vets == null) {
         vets = new ArrayList<Vet>();
       }
      return vets;
   }


  }
```

The service:

```
@Service
@ManagedResource("petclinic:type=Clinic")
public class SimpleJdbcClinic implements Clinic, SimpleJdbcClinicMBean {

    private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertOwner;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertPet;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertVisit;

    private final List<Vet> vets = new ArrayList<Vet>();
       :
       :
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Collection<Vet> getVets() throws DataAccessException {
         synchronized (this.vets) {
             if (this.vets.isEmpty()) {
                 refreshVetsCache();
             }
             return this.vets;
         }
    }
}
```

The controller mapping:

```
 @RequestMapping("/vets")
 public ModelMap vetsHandler() {
     Vets vets = new Vets();
     vets.getVetList().addAll(this.clinic.getVets());
     return new ModelMap(vets);
  }
```

Once the vets list is created it survives multiple requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it avoids redundant database calls by storing all vets in the `private final List<Vet> vets`. Also `vets` variable is a property of a singleton `@Service SimpleJdbcClinic`

Comment: Yes, but isn't SimpleJdbcClinic request scoped?

Comment: Default scope is Singleton. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: I believe it should be singleton in this example as well.

Comment: Okay, for some reason I thought that only applied to @controller, not all beans. I should have checked, thanks. This is what happens when you're a beginner.